# Help to find missing tokens

Tags: gas-estimate, pancakeswap, liquidity-provider

Actually, it's become a little complex. I am missing around 2 million-plus tokens now.
Here are the actions I have done.

1. Purchased GenshinShibInu tokens for $129 using Binance Smart Chain Wallet in Pancakeswap. (wallet address: 0xc013F7002a4e2ae8c5Aa0E575E42C8b5cdb48A81).
2. As per my purchase, at that time my wallet showed me I had around 2 million-plus tokens.
3. I added liquidity pool of BNB + GenshinShibInu token in Pancakeswap. Transaction Hash: 0xa4e5d2f6bb24233ae8a48ea7286cd4218ba27741ae71e7b2455abb08004bcb2c
4. I think this is the ddress of the LP token: 0x4fb94afb28d1c6a828834a4b4fc200719c1c25df but not sure if I am right.
5. I started removing the LP token in Pancakeswap using the same Binance Smart Chain Wallet but the confirm button didn't perform any action but only gave me an error stating "cannot estimate gas".
6. I tried all possible percentages of LP token and also slippage percentage but still didn't work.
7. Finally I transferred all my tokens from Binance Smart Chain Wallet to Metamask wallet (Address: 0x1DFA31B655121002529ccABC974B16fF8658e751) Smart Chain network including other tokens and LP tokens.
8. Now I connected Pancakeswap with my Metamask wallet and tried to remove the LP pool tokens 2 times.

   1. Tried removing 25% to test. Transaction hash: 0x087499dcea9851a136f70b6898d8f4a847a6278c8f27a766e957a08a4b82a409
   2. Remove the remaining %. Transaction hash: 0x4fdbe48d07499c311358f6768e5ac2fc4e7042c3ce8e00116b7267d76c82f5e2
9. Both worked well.
10. But finally after removing all liquidity pools I received 0 BNB and 0 GenshinShibInu tokens back to my wallet.
11. Also after I added liquidity pool the first time, I had around 30k GenshinShibInu tokens in my wallet and this was getting reduced day by day and now I have only 280 GenshinShibInu tokens.

So kindly help me understand how did I lose all my tokens. And if possible kindly help me get back my tokens.

Comment: What's the pool address? What's the token address?

Comment: It will be better to edit the question and add those details there.

Comment: Hi Ismael, please find the updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer lies in the below link:

genshinshibinu is basically cheating its customers. Please don't buy

https://community.trustwallet.com/t/genshinshibinu-tokens-are-missing/325702

Comment: Hi Jane! Welcome to Ethereum Stackexchange! Link only answers are discouraged. It will better to include the main idea "elastic supply tokens might adjust the balance" in the answer and only use the link to fill the details..

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).